# GitHub Actions - How To Work With TypeScript

Tags: typescript, github, github-actions, building-github-actions

## The Problem

I'm doing a custom GitHub Action for the Marketplace, to make it easier to use in other projects.

The Action is made with TypeScript, and uses some packages, like `typescript`, `babel` (**edit:** don't use babel anymore), `@actions/core` and `@actions/github`.

When I add the Action to the workflow of another project, he can install the packages and build the project, even initialize it, but when the execution starts, he cannot find the @actions modules and the **core of @actions/core is undefined** (@actions/core is the first package to be used, because of this, it crashed the pipeline).

The `node_modules` folder **is correctly created and the packages are inside it**, but inside the script, they don't are loaded.

## The Probable Cause

When I try to run the built version (both builder version, the one with ncc and the one with tsc) on my machine, this same error happens:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'getInput' of undefined
```

**EDIT:** The problem was the incorrect import of the package `@actions/core`

## Aditional Info

In order to be able to install the packages and build, I had to do this in my `action.yml` file:

```yaml
runs:
  using: "composite"
  steps:
    - run: cd ${{ github.action_path }}
      shell: bash
    - run: yarn --cwd ${{ github.action_path }} --production=true
      shell: bash
    - run: yarn --cwd ${{ github.action_path }} build
      shell: bash
    - run: yarn --cwd ${{ github.action_path }} start
      shell: bash
```

My folder structure:

```
|-dist # THIS IS'NT BEING PUSHED TO THE REPO
|-src
|--index.ts # Where the @actions/core is required
|--... # More files that are imported by index.ts
|-node_modules # THIS IS'NT BEING PUSHED TO THE REPO
|--... # All the packages are here, this is right and ISN'T THE PROBLEM
|-action.yml
|-babel.config.js
|-package.json
|-tsconfig.json
|-yarn.lock
```

With the action.yml I sent above, the following error is returned:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'getInput' of undefined
```

`getInput` is a method of `@actions/core` (which is being imported correctly and **ISN'T THE PROBLEM**)

**EDIT:** That was the problem hahaha.

---

If I don't run `yarn install` or `npm install` with some script, the following error happens:

```
Error: Cannot find module '@actions/core'
```

In the tutorials I saw, none of them needed to install the packages, it was as like they were installed automatically.

---

I also tried with [ncc](https://github.com/vercel/ncc) and push the compiled code to the action repo, but it also didn't work.

My action.yml:

```yaml
runs:
  using: "node12"
  main: "index.js"
```

My folder structure:

```
|-src
|--index.ts # Where the @actions/core is required
|--... # More files that are imported by index.ts
|-node_modules # THIS IS'NT BEING PUSHED TO THE REPO
|--... # All the packages are here, this is right and ISN'T THE PROBLEM
|-action.yml
|-index.js # The compiled code, that is being pushed to the repo
|-package.json
|-tsconfig.json
|-yarn.lock
```

With the config above, this same error happens:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'getInput' of undefined
```

---

This is how I'm importing `@actions/core` in the first line of `src/index.ts`:

```
import core from "@actions/core";
```

---

- I'm not pushing the node_modules to the repository, just the dist folder (I tried without the folder too, building during the action execution, but it also didn't work.)
- I also found [this article](https://medium.com/better-programming/build-github-actions-with-typescript-bc0442572825), but it also didn't work.

## The Questions

- Any ideas about how do I work with typescript in GitHub Actions?
- Why the modules aren't loaded?
- Is there any tutorial, article, video, any type of content about work with TypeScript with GitHub Actions for Marketplace? I found [this template](https://medium.com/better-programming/build-github-actions-with-typescript-bc0442572825), but I'm not able to found out why this works and mine doesn't (I haven't tested the template, maybe it doesn't work too).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I finally discovered the problem.

To work with `@actions/core` in TypeScript, this is the correct way to import it:

```
import * as core from "@actions/core"
```

You need to put a `* as`.

Sorry for the incorrect information I gave in the description of the question, I was sure I was importing it the right way.

For more details of the project, [this is my action](https://github.com/henriqueleite42/action-heroku-deploy)

Comment: Why * as, if I am using typescript imports with `allowSyntheticDefaultImports`?

Answer (score 1):

You defined a `Composite run steps action` instead of a `JavaScript action`.

See [explanation of action types](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/creating-actions/about-actions#types-of-actions).

If you look at [this TypeScript action template](https://github.com/actions/typescript-action), it has the `dist` folder checked in and refers to it in its `action.yaml` in the property `runs.main`.

This means you should compile your TypeScript action locally and check in the `dist` folder. It also says to use `ncc` to compile to a single file.
As described [here](https://github.com/actions/typescript-action#publish-to-a-distribution-branch).

```
name: 'Your name here'
description: 'Provide a description here'
author: 'Your name or organization here'
inputs:
  milliseconds: # change this
    required: true
    description: 'input description here'
    default: 'default value if applicable'
runs:
  using: 'node12'
  main: 'dist/index.js'
```

Comment: I tried with ncc (https://github.com/vercel/ncc) but it also didn't work. I will edit the questions to add more detailed information.